# Libgdx: choosing different preference files for saving data

Tags: java, android, libgdx, preferences, filehandle

So what I'm trying to do is have different files to save custom level data so than the player can make their own level, save it and than later on choose which level to load, now I know there's the default `FileHandle` class, but that only saves a single string and that a problem for me because the way I'm saving it is I'm loading each object into an `ArrayList`, turning that `ArrayList` into a `JSON` string and then saving that string under the rooms ID for that level, so the Preference file would look like

```
Room ID 1
Json string 
Room ID 2
JSON string 
Room ID 3
Etc etc
```

Which is why using `FileHandle` wouldn't work because all the `JSON` strings would be saved together and I can't think of a way to separate them

So the question I'm asking is, using Preferences, is there a way I can allow the player to choose which file to load? Because the only way I can think of is to save each preference file's name in another file and loading that, but that's a bit convoluted and doesn't allow the player to load in New files if they get one from a friend for example

Comment: What is preventing you from writing the json to a file then reading it back from that file? Or creating a separate file for each level containing only the json string relevant to that level?

Comment: That's not the problem, the problem is I'm trying to make it so I can have the player click a button that says 'load level' and than a little dialogue box pops up and they choose which preference file to load from, I'm just not sure how to do that or if it's even possible

Comment: Just use `FileHandle#list()` to list the files in whatever directory you store the files in. Plop those into a `List` or `SelectBox` widget and let the user choose. I wouldn't use `Preferences` for this.